# Is there a way to intercept attached files using Discord.js and delete messages with certain file types?

Tags: javascript, automation, discord, discord.js

I know I can use JavaScript to do the scanning for filetypes, and I know how to delete the messages. That isn't a problem. I just don't know if it's possible to intercept attached files with discord.js. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you are looking to delete a message that contains a specific file type. This is how you would do that:

```
const fileTypes = ['.jpg']; //leave the file types here

message.attachments.forEach(attachment => { //iterates over all attachments
  for (fileType of fileTypes) { //iterates over all the file types provided
    if (attachment.name.includes(fileType)) { //checks if the name of the attachment includes the file type
      message.delete() // if yes, deletes

      message.channel.send(`Message deleted because it contains a ${fileType} file`);
    };
  };
});
```